# What types of tubing can I use with Push-to-Connect fittings?

Tags: plumbing, fitting

I'm running a hydrogen gas system that's below 15 psi. All of my fittings are Push-to-Connect fittings of either 3/16", 1/4", or 5/16" OD from SMC. What sort of tubing can I use with this?

Would everyday hardware store vinyl tubing work fine? Nylon tubing? ATP Vinyl-Flex PVC? I can't find any literature about this on the SMC website.

Comment: Are the push fittings themselves compatible with H gas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use tubing that is rated for hydrogen gas. McMaster-Carr may have some. Likely you'll have to use stainless steel or an exotic plastic like teflon. Normal hardware-store tubing will react, possibly violently, when used with such fluids/gasses in them. If you're cracking water into hydrogen / oxygen, that line will need to also be customized for carrying mostly pure oxygen.

Comment: What about copper or black iron? The former at least can be used with push fittings.

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever used more rigid plastics like polyethylene tubing with push to connect tubing. I would not trust vinyl, as it's soft and tends to creep more. In that vein, I'd say nylon is ok too. I'm unfamiliar with that type. Of pvc.